# Can you change css with a click function?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am making a battleship style game and trying to work on the movement of the ships on the table. My idea is that you can drag and drop ships onto the table and when you click on the ship it changes from vertical to a horizontal position or other way around. Every ship has some css with two main parts Width and Height. Is it possible to make so that the Ships css width and height are swapped around when I click on the ship?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Yes you can, do you want to apply that using **VueJs** or **JavaScript**?
Please share your code snippet to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript, you can change the CSS width using:

```
var el = document.querySelector("#yourObjectID");
el.style.width = "100px";
```

To change the height:

```
el.style.height = "100px";
```

To swap the height and width you could use an extra variable as you would swap any other variables.

If you are using a click listener, you can use `this` instead of creating a variable `el` and selecting the element with a query selector.

```js
document.querySelector("#ship1").addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newHeight = this.style.width;
  this.style.width = this.style.height;
  this.style.height = newHeight;
}, false);
```

```css
.ship {
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div id="ship1" class="ship" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfortunately not too sure what you are trying to achieve. are you trying to swap the ships from vertical to horizontal or are you trying  to swap the width and height with eachother.

If you are trying to rotate the ship you can do it like this:

With css and js you can rotate the ships like this:

html

```
<div id="MyID" onclick="ChangeClass()"></div>
```

js

```
function ChangeClass() {

var MyVar= document.getElementById("MyID")

MyVar.className="MyClass"

}
```

css

```
.MyClass{
/* rotates the class. webkit = chrome,safari ms = edge, moz = firefox, o = opera*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

you can change the ID and classes to your desired names.